# VBA, Using range on two separate cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy cells `B5` and `F5` and paste them into cell `A1` and `B1` in a different sheet. To that end I'm copying those cells using the below code:

```
 Range(cell.address, cell.Offset(0, 4).address).copy
```

But that's selecting B5 through F5, not the individual cells. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your range is not processed the way you expect (it's treated as contiguous)

Use this syntax:

```
Range(cel.Address & "," & cel.Offset(0, 4).Address).Copy
```

Comment: Worked. Could you elaborate on your comment ? I didn't fully understand it. Are you saying that the 'range' considers the items as one input and not  arguments separated by commas ? Where could I found that out ? Note: How can I add a line break in comments ?

Comment: Sure. Here is one link from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211367(v=office.12).aspx) for references to ranges (I had another link but can't find it now). Just some examples: `Range("C5:D9,G9:H16")` (multiple-areas), `Range("1:1,3:3,8:8")` (rows 1, 3, and 8), and `Range("A:A,C:C,F:F")` (columns A, C, and F)

Comment: Sorry, I missed your last question: to add a line break in comments you can use vbCrLf / Chr(13) + Chr(10), vbCr / Chr(13), vbLf / Chr(10), vbNewLine / Chr(13) + Chr(10)/Chr(13); something like: `Cells(1, 1).AddComment: Cells(1, 1).Comment.Text Text:="abc" & Chr(10) & "def"`

Comment: I actually meant in stackoverflow comments (right here). Two spaces at the end isn't working for me.  test

Comment: I see - these comments are quite limited (I don't think you can add a line break) but to see what you can do in them click the "help" link to the right: _Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:  [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work_